# How to select a file for file uploader in a Selenium test on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

am writing a Selenium test that requires a file to be chosen and uploaded to continue to the next page. I currently can have the Mac browser window to drop down from the top when the test clicks the input, but it is not selecting the file. The file is in the same folder as the story that is currently being run.

I am new to Selenium but I did not think something like this would pose such a large issue.

I am currently using  the following in my robot:

```
element("[name='file']").click();
    WebElement elem1 = driver.findElement(By.name("input[@name='file']"));
    elem1.sendKeys(filePath);
```

Comment: **Remove the first line for clicking on the file** and try. Because, **if you click on the input button(or upload button), then a dialog box comes up and it goes out of the context of browser and selenium can't handle it.** Just use the last 2 lines of above code.

Comment: In addition to not clicking, you may also need to set the [`LocalFileDetector`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/LocalFileDetector.html) to find local files (especially if you are running against a remote grid, for example).